# Adding careers section to linguistics

Tags: feature-request

I would really like to see the careers section in Linguistics SE. I know that linguistics is still in Beta and we don't have much users but the site is grwoing so fast and it would be great to have this feature.

Comment: are there career sections on any SE sites, apart from the SO site? I don't know if such a thing is possible.

Comment: Well there aren't because most of them are specific sites (I say most because I haven't checked all of them). Server fault, android, etc. aren't career subjects but linguistics is. Also What do you mean by impossible? The admins are not willing to add this feature? Or the premise of having careers section for linguistics is impossible?

Comment: The admins have to roll out this feature. Are you aware of any SE site that has it?

Comment: @prash no other SE site has it.

Comment: I don't think we have enough professional linguists for this to be practical. Are we really growing fast? To me, the site seems to be going along at a consistent but slow pace.

Comment: @sumelic I agree. But starting and launching the project can take some time and we will reach that point at the time launching it. Right?

Comment: I just can't see it being a priority for Stack Exchange at any point in the foreseeable future. Which means, it won't just take some time, it will never happen because nobody will be working on it. They are interested in extending Careers to some other sites eventually (as described in the answer to this question: [Extend Careers to other sites (like Ask Ubuntu), not just Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251063)) but I think they're focusing on tech sector jobs. Still, it can't hurt for you to make this post to gauge how much interest people here have in the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Questions on any SE site should not just be personal opinions, they should be objective truths about the subject matter, where there is a definite right answer. I have a hard time seeing how a career question could meet that desideratum. E.g. any answer to a question like "should I double major in Linguistics and Computer Science to be sure of getting a job" is just going to be made up and will not take into consideration the questioner's abilities, and will not be generalizable to the next person who has the same question. Even actual fact questions like "How many academic jobs where there in 2015 in the area of phonology" will only generate off-topic personal opinions.

Comment: I was not asking about adding career as a question base for linguistics. Careers section is a part of Stackoverflow where people can add their resumes and jobs matching their skills appear. A similar thing for linguistics SE would be like when you are visiting phonetics tags you will see job postings about phonetics.